# Is it not a good practise to make api calls during database transactions?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, transactions

I am writing a function which needs to call an external api and save the results to postgres database. And I am thinking the pros and cons on two approaches:

1. Start a transaction, lock the row by using SELECT FOR UPDATE, make api call and save the results, and roll back if one of them fails.
2. Call the api first, and then start a transaction, lock the row by using SELECT FOR UPDATE, and write the result, only if the api call succeeds and returns result.

I have heard that involving external api calls in database transaction are extremely dangerous. But I am not sure what other reasons there are, besides the obvious reason that the transaction might take a longer time. Will there be any difference depending HTTP method we are using for the api calls? (GET vs POST)

I am learning towards the second approach if we are only getting information from the api call and writing to database. This way we don't hold the transaction for too long. But on the other hand, I don't see anything wrong with the transaction taking long, if it does not block read operation, and if no other subsequent actions are being blocked by this transaction or the row being locked.

Looking for some opinions here. Would appreciate some examples on each of the approach, thanks!

Comment: The second way is the correct way. Locking DB rows for longer than necessary slows things down even to the point of deadlock. I have worked on projects where we refactored from 1 to 2.

Comment: [Fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)

Comment: Embedding one risky long-running network-based operation within another risky long-running network-based operation is generally unwise. Makes for more complications in your programming, logging, and debugging.

Comment: For the 2nd option, there is no (apparent) reason to do a SELECT FOR UPDATE.  Just do the UPDATE.

Comment: What are the consequences of making the same API call on the same row more than once at a time?  If doing that is expensive or catastrophic, you wouldn't want to use option 2.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for the first comment, you are correct, this was probably just specific to my application where we need to load the object before saving the data. Generally a simple UPDATE like you said should be enough. 

For the second comment, the cost of calling more than once is low in our case, so no worries there.

Answer (score 2):

Due to connection to DB is a limited resource, usually connections controlled by connection pool sub-systems, Hikari, for instance.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

So, I assume, you have a connection pool in your application. Every transaction you gonna hold longer than needed, gonna hold a connection too. A pool usually have restrictions over connections, which prevents connection pool from exhaustion. For example, if you are using Hikari you would face some problems in case of long term external API calls, because:

1. Connection pool allows you to have 10 connections to DB by default, you hold 10 transactions, which consequently holds 10 connections, so, your read connection have no chance to catch a connection (of course, it have but transactions start racing for connection)
2. If you have long request to external API, pool can break a connection by timeout at some point and your data would be lost, despite you have response from external service, you won't save it.

For example you can check Hikari limitations here: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java

More interested, those

```
    private static final long CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = SECONDS.toMillis(30);
    ...
    private static final int DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE = 10;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment! This is a legit reason not to have transactions long while having a big load on the service